# RPI2 and RPI3 docker and usb support

Tags: pi-2, usb, driver, docker

I am working with my RPI2 device where is minibian with Docker where is Alpine linux for controll which is for work...
I receantly using cython-hidapi for communicate with HID device (python3 lib). Everything is ok but, when i took sd card from rpi2 and put it into rpi3 usb hid communication is sometimes not correct.
Is it possible that RPI2 and RPI3 had not compatible usb drivers (same compilation of hidapi) ?

Thanks Mike